# Hyperforce migration impact on Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, migration, hyperforce

My client is planning to move salesforce service cloud infra to salesforce hyperforce. SFMC is connected to CRM via MCC where Tenant Endpoints for Oauth is already Enabled. This is my first migration experience can anyone help me to know what would be impact on sfmc during migration will IER go back to crm as usual or MCC setup will break .

Answer (score 1):

If you have followed the steps in this article

- [Enabling Tenant-Specific OAuth Endpoints for Marketing Cloud Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390168&type=1)
- [Updating Marketing Cloud Endpoints to Tenant Specific Endpoints: FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392227&type=1)

There would be no disruption.

Answer (score 1):

More generally related to Hyperforce Migration it is worth reading:

- [How to Prepare for an Org Migration](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386897&type=1)